# numpyの相関係数について

Tags: python3, numpy

こんにちは、pythonのnumpyについて質問させていただきます。
相関係数を計算する際に、 `numpy.corrcoef(XとYの二次元配列)` を使用すれば計算できますが、数式の確認のために公式である `共分散 / (Xの標準偏差 * Yの標準偏差）` で相関係数を出したいと考え、 `numpy.cov(XとYの二次元配列）/ (numpy.std(X)*numpy.std(Y))` で計算しましたが、なぜか `numpy.corrcoef(XとYの二次元配列)` と同じ結果になりませんでした。この原因をどなたか教えていただければ幸いです。

それぞれの値は以下のとおりです。
・`numpy.corrcoef(XとYの二次元配列)`：

```
array([[ 1.        , -0.55847735],
       [-0.55847735,  1.        ]])
```

・`numpy.cov(XとYの二次元配列）`：

```
array([[ 7.01969195e-01, -2.42092650e+01],
       [-2.42092650e+01,  2.67691160e+03]])
```

・`numpy.std(X)`：

```
0.8375159287888337
```

・`numpy.std(Y)`：

```
51.719112506809196
```

・`numpy.cov(XとYの二次元配列）/ (numpy.std(X)*numpy.std(Y))`:

```
array([[ 1.61935480e-02, -5.58477348e-01],
       [-5.58477348e-01,  6.17529897e+01]])
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`np.cov()`はデフォルトで`ddof=1`である一方、`np.std()`はデフォルトでは`ddof=0`になっています。
したがって`np.std()`に`ddof=1`を指定すると`np.corrcoef()`と同じ結果が得られます。

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.seed(0)
   ...: X, Y = np.random.rand(2, 1000)

In [3]: np.corrcoef(X, Y)
Out[3]:
array([[1.        , 0.00601658],
       [0.00601658, 1.        ]])

# NG
In [4]: np.cov(X, Y) / (np.std(X) * np.std(Y))
Out[4]:
array([[0.97301135, 0.0060226 ],
       [0.0060226 , 1.0297958 ]])

# OK
In [5]: np.cov(X, Y) / (np.std(X, ddof=1) * np.std(Y, ddof=1))
Out[5]:
array([[0.97203834, 0.00601658],
       [0.00601658, 1.028766  ]])
```

なお念の為に言うと、左上と右下が`1.`になっていないのは、XとXの共分散（Xの分散）およびYとYの共分散（Yの分散）で割るべきところまでXとYの共分散で割っているからです。